# Keras fails to find solution to linear convex problem

Tags: python, numpy, keras, linear-regression

I wrote this **reproducible** code to demonstrate the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

n, d = 2, 3
A = np.random.random((n, d))
b = np.random.random((n, 1))
x = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)[0]
print("Numpy MSE is {}".format((np.linalg.norm(A @ x - b) ** 2) / n))

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, use_bias=False, activation='linear'))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0, nesterov=False)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opt)
model.fit(A, b, batch_size=A.shape[0], epochs=10000, verbose=0)
x = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
print("Keras MSE is {}".format((np.linalg.norm(A @ x - b) ** 2) / n))
```

Basically I am solving under-determined system of linear equations `Ax=b` in two ways, once with numpy, and once with keras standard gradient descent.

When I run it, I get this output:

```
Numpy MSE is 6.162975822039155e-33
Keras MSE is 1.3108133821545518e-10
```

numpy yields a much better result, but I'm still willing to accept keras as a solution, 10^(-10) is fairly small.

Now increase n to 200 and d to 300.
The output is now:

```
Numpy MSE is 1.4348640308871558e-30
Keras MSE is 0.0001953624326696054
```

Now not only that numpy is much better, but as far as I am concerned, keras did not find a solution. The result we got is not close enough to zero, and I am stuck. Changing the learning rate or adding iterations does not change the result significantly. Why does this happen?

I know there's a solution. I want the error to be at most 10^(-10), using keras, for large dimensional data such as the n = 200 d = 300 case

**TLDR**: I'm desperately trying to overfit. I know there's a solution that gives me 0 loss. My problem is linear and convex, classic under-determined system, keras won't find that solution and give me 0 training loss.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this as opinion-based (and perhaps also downvoted) and reviewers: this is a perfectly legitimate coding question with a **fully reproducible** example (a rarity nowadays), and there is nothing opinion-based in it.

Comment: Irrelevant to your issue, but it's not a good idea to mix the stand-alone `keras` with `tf.keras`; I suggest you remove `import keras` and replace `keras` in your code with `tf.keras`.

Comment: I didn't vote for anything, but I am wondering if this question isn't comparing apples and oranges? I don't know how `np.linalg.lstsq` computes its solution, but I cannot find a reference to gradient descent in the docs. As such, comparing it to Keras with SGD is not fair. At the very least, a decaying learning rate schedule should be used to (theoretically) guarantee convergence. Also, the question should include a specific random seed for the generated data -- as it is, desertnauts better results may simply be due to chance.

Comment: @xdurch0 fair point for the random seed, but replicating the provided code several times even w/o it I got results very similar with the ones reported. The solution I suggested changed this consistently, even for multiple runs. `np.linalg.lstsq` most probably doesn't use SGD, but I understand in principle an expectation that Keras should not perform that badly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `input_shape` argument in the layer definition. Not quite sure why it does not work without a defined `input_shape` (the shape of the weights seems OK); but, according to the [documentation](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/#specifying-the-input-shape-in-advance):

> In general, it's a recommended best practice to always specify the input shape of a Sequential model in advance if you know what it is.

The other thing is, by setting `batch_size=A.shape[0]`, you are actually using *batch* gradient descent, and not *stochastic*; in order to use SGD, you need to set a `batch_size` smaller than the size of your data sample.

So, with the following changes in your code in the high-dimensional case (plus replacing all `keras` uses with `tf.keras`, since mixing the two is not good practice):

```
# n, d = 200, 300

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(A.shape[1],), use_bias=False, activation='linear'))

model.fit(A, b, batch_size=32, epochs=10000, verbose=0)
```

after 10,000 epochs, the result is:

```
Keras MSE is 1.9258555439788135e-10
```

while iterating for 10,000 more epochs (i.e. total 20,000), we get:

```
Keras MSE is 1.2521153241468356e-13
```

Repeating the runs, we get qualitatively similar (but of course not identical) results.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do anything else? I'm still getting bad results.

Comment: @OriaGruber you are right - my apologies :( . I also used `batch_size=32` (plus the mentioned change `keras` -> `tf.keras`). I am updating the answer...

Comment: But that's changing the algorithm. This is now no longer "vanilla" gradient descent. That's nice but not very helpful to me as I'm working with theorem that deal with regular GD, not anything stochastic.

Comment: @OriaGruber not sure what you mean by "vanilla", since SGD is what is actually used in practice; but in any case, feel free to un-accept the answer if it does not actually address your question, thus keeping it open and inviting other ideas (I will admit that this Keras behavior is *very* strange, and you might be better off posting this to the Keras/Tensorflow repo as a possible issue).

Comment: By vanilla I mean x = x - learning_rate * df/dx. Steepest descent. I know it's not used in practice often. I will keep this answer as accepted.